# From ARCore Sample app, how to draw face mesh lines?

Tags: opengl-es, arcore, face

[image]

From augmented_faces_java Sample code in [arcore-android-sdk](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk), how do I add face mesh lines?

Comment: Have you found any solution? Then please tell me.

Comment: No, no luck yet